# filter_condition_callback having issues if value is backslash "\"

Tags: magento-1.9

My `filter_condition_callback` is working fine in `sales_order_grid`

```
protected function _phoneColumnFilter($collection, $column) 
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    $orderCollection->getSelect()->join(
            array('address' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
            'main_table.entity_id=address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing"',
            array('telephone' => 'GROUP_CONCAT(address.telephone)')
        )->group('main_table.entity_id')->having('telephone = "'. $value .'"');

    $filteredOrderIds = array();
    foreach($orderCollection as $order){
        $filteredOrderIds[$order->getId()] = $order->getId();
    }

    $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $filteredOrderIds));

    return $this;
}
```

This yeilds this `sql string`:

> SELECT `main_table`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(address.telephone) AS `telephone`
>   FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`  INNER JOIN
>   `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON
>   main_table.entity_id=address.parent_id AND address.address_type =
>   "billing" GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` HAVING (telephone =
>   "123456")

**The problem occurs when user tries to search by `\` (backslash).**

The query string:

> SELECT `main_table`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(address.telephone) AS `telephone`
>   FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`  INNER JOIN
>   `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON
>   main_table.entity_id=address.parent_id AND address.address_type =
>   "billing" GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` HAVING (telephone = "\")

Above throws this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '"\")' at line 2

**How do I prevent this?**